# How Many Times Does a Value Occur in a Month?

Tags: excel

I've got data that looks like:

Date |ID Number
9/6/2013    |ABCDE
11/26/2013  |LMNOP
3/25/2014   |VWXYZ
3/27/2014   |VWXYZ
4/8/2014    |VWXYZ
4/10/2014   |VWXYZ

I was wondering if there was a code that would allow me to count up a particular number of times an ID Number was associated with a particular month. My data has been sorted by ID Number, and I need to know how many times the Number occurs per month.

For example, I would need to know that in a column for March that VWXYZ occurred twice, and the same in a column for April. I need to know if there is a formula for automatically searching for the ID Number and counting how many times that Number is associated with a particular month. Everywhere I look, it involves manually entering the ID Number into the formula.  I have almost two thousand entries in my data sheet, and I was hoping there was an easier way.

This has stumped me for days, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you think you could spend a little longer formatting the data block?

Comment: This is possible. But I need to know how you would want the results to be presented.

Comment: I would need to put the values in a column based on the month they occurred, having the total in the same row as the ID Number. I know this would repeat some of the data if the Number occurred twice or more, but it's how I'm told I'm to do it. I apologize for my lack of brevity with replying, I'm swamped with work and a little flustered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Date` is in A1, the start date for your chosen month is in D1 and the string to search for in E1 please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D1,A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(D1,0),B:B,E1)
```

*Edit re OP's comment to question*

In row2 and copied down to suit:

```
 =COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1,A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(A2,0),B:B,B2)
```